# Why doesn't my countdown timer switch to my other activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a countdown timer that automatically switches from one activity (home
activity) to my another activity(home). The problem is that the code will count but wouldn't display my 2nd activity, and it would go back to my main activity. Does anyone know the solution to this?

This is my code for my timer:

```
package com.login.register;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Timer timer;
    //---------------------------Timer--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent t = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(t);
                finish();
            }
        }, 3000);}}
```

Here is my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.login.register">

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Edit Your post and add code in:  ``` YOUR CODE ```, not in image

Answer (score 0):

Add below code Inside `onCreate()`  of first activity :

**Kotlin Code:**

```
Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {
            startActivity(Intent(this@HomeActivity,Home::class.java))// Home class should be an activity and should be declared in Manifest file 
        },5000)//5 sec delay
```

**Java Code:**

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Home.class)); //Home class should be an activity and should be declared in Manifest file 
            }
        },5000); // 5 sec delay
```

`java.util.Timer` and `android.os.Handler` both are kinda Thread but handler is much faster than timer in term of performance. see this [diff b/w handler and timer](https://medium.com/@dnkilic/very-simple-comparison-between-java-util-timer-and-android-os-handler-ea6749038b12)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering me!! I have a question regarding the code. First one, is what is handler and how can I get the file that includes this? Also, is this what you were referring to on my Xtml, i just want to be sure. *I added the Manifest file*

Comment: Hi @brandongriffith i have updated code regarding Timer and Handler

Comment: Hey @chand mohd can you please teach me how to do that?

Comment: Yes, the code still doesn't stay on my second activity. Is it because of my android manifest?

Comment: Your code seems fine ..but the problem is with your “Home.class” check two things :1) make sure Home.class should be subclass of an activity .2) it’s should be declared in Manifest file same as you declare HomeActivity.java